# .wrap() doesnt work on custom XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

so I have this xml

```
<Item name="Alpha">
   <Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>
   <Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>
</Item>
<Item name="Beta">
  <Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>
  <Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>
</Item>
```

And I want to wrap this inside a node like this using jQuery

```
<parent>
 <Item name="Alpha">
   <Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>
   <Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>
</Item>
<Item name="Beta">
  <Field name="CreationDateTime">2012-04-26</Field>
  <Field name="Material" readOnly="X"> Congress </Field>
</Item></parent>
```

I tried `$(xml).wrap('<parent />')` but it doesnt seem to be working for non html tags names! Likewise I tried combination of before() and append() too.

Is there any way to quickly do it in jQuery without having to convert it into string.  If thats the last option then how do I convert into string and do it?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery wasn't designed to work with XML nodes that way. You should use JavaScript's native DOM capabilities to manipulate XML.

Comment: Are you actually working wth an XMLDoc? or did you simply do $(xmlstring).wrap()

Comment: @Kevin...I am working with real XMLDoc...

Answer (score 0):

You can apply xsl to wrap the xml doc, example

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <parent>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

should get you the output you want

Comment: Where are you getting the source xml from? Your second <item> is missing a closing </item>, and your xml should have a root by default.

Comment: getting it from a server file. sorry about </item>... i have updated it.

Comment: @nicholmikey... its good that you brought the xsl piece- (I have never applied xsl before and was curious to know more about it)... to start with, how do I apply this on xml (I mean the syntax to do in javascript)... do I need a jQuery plugin to support xsl? Please note that this is happening at client side.